# Unable to compile C++ code with simulink with libmwfl.so errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, matlab, compiler-errors, simulink

We are trying to compile some C++ code with simulink /matlab . We are getting some libmwfl.so errors. We have made sure that the files are linked . Also on doing a search for the file libmwfl.so it seems that it exists. So at the moment a bit clueleess. The error log is as below.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwfl.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwi18n.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Regards

Comment: Do you have those libraries installed on your system anywhere? Have you tried using the `-rpath` option as suggested?

Comment: Hello again it worked !